# get website root in dev and prod without hard-coding anything

Tags: php

My dev server is `http://localhost/mygreatapp` and my production server is `http://www.myawesomesite.com` but maybe someday it will migrate to `http://www.myawesomesite.com/mygreatapp`

In these cases `mygreatapp` is a virtual directory.

I would like a php function to return the correct website roots without having to hard-code anything (e.g., `mygreatapp`), regardless if it's off the default website or a virtual directory. In either case, that's where all the relative paths to the files begins.

I have looked at the similar questions and not found a solution that does not involve hard-coding, which would then involve having to update the value for each environment, painful and error prone.

Comment: You're not explaining the context.  something like <?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

Comment: @LucasHolt, see my edit and maybe you can undo your downvote

Comment: Well it sounds like you're assuming PHP works like ASP.net or maybe a  tomcat instance.  It's not like that.  Usually PHP is mapped for a while domain on a unix system.  I'm guessing you're using IIS by the terminology you're using.  

A PHP app isn't really like that.  It's more like a script interpreter mapped for files with a given file extension.  It doesn't really have a concept of a web root.  That's why i suggested getting the value from the environment variables.

Comment: @LucasHolt, I think I can use `realpath` to get what  I want, based on what I know about my website structure, which won't change between environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get my by for now, but I'll need to adjust it if I go into a subfolder on a linux machine.

```
public static function WebRoot(){
        $virtualdir = '';
        if(isset($_SERVER['APPL_MD_PATH'])){
            $virtualdir = substr($_SERVER['APPL_MD_PATH'], strpos($_SERVER['APPL_MD_PATH'], '/ROOT/') + strlen('/ROOT/'));
        }
        return 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'.$virtualdir.'/';
}
```